# How do I check last visited date on particular web page ? I want to show link expired after 7 days on that page

Tags: php, html, browser

I want to store the first visited date on that browser and after 7 days I want to show some other content on that web page. So how do check that when that user visited the web page the first time? I want to keep that content visible only for 7 days.How do I achieve this with php code ?
Please help me with this.

Comment: You can use cookie, I think it's a good practice for that kind of job.

Comment: local browser storage is another useful data storage mechanism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, you can use:
[cookies](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)
[setcookie](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Example:

```
// When a user visit that page, you will check whether a cookie is     
// set or not. If not, then you can set a cookie with the current time     
// as its value. If already set, then check if its time is greater than      
// 7 days or not.

$showContent = true;
$datetime = new \DateTime(); 
$now = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //current datetime

//check cookie
if(!isset($_COOKIE['pageVisitTime'])) {
    setcookie("pageVisitTime", $now, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));  /* using a far future date */
} else {
    $pageVisitTime = $_COOKIE['pageVisitTime'];
    $visitDateTime = new \DateTime($pageVisitTime);
    if($visitDateTime->diff($datetime)->days > 7) {
       $showContent = false;
    }
}

//Depending on value of $showContent you can control your content
```

Comment: @AkshayDongare Glad to hear that. Please accept the answer if solution worked for you.